# Random Assignment of Groups

Tags: r

How do I randomly assign a group of people into four treatment groups and a control group, given that I have a list of their names on an excel document?

Answer (score 4):

Get the randomizr package

```
install.packages("randomizr")
library(randomizr)
```

use complete random assignment (holds the number of units assigned to each condition fixed across randomizations, unlike `sample` with `replace = TRUE`

```
Z <- complete_ra(N = 100, num_arms = 5)
table(Z)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 100 names (number them as such) then you can assign them to one of 5 groups with

```
split(1:100, sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

`split(x, f)` splits `x` into groups according to `f`, for which I've used `sample` to sample 100 occurrences of the numbers 1 to 5 (with replacement).

Take these numbered names from your list.

(Note: you didn't specify *equal* groups).

Alternatively, the `caret` package can handle this quite nicely for you: https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html